# iOS - my heightForRowAtIndexPath implementation causes performance issues, why?

Tags: ios, objective-c, performance, uitableview

I use a table view where I override `heightForRowAtIndexPath`. When I run the Xcode profiler I found the following:

[image]

I want to calculate the height based one object's property. I use the same table view for two kind of objects, `User` and `Post`. My implementation currently looks like this:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *text;
    Post *cellPost;
    User *cellUser;
    if (_pageType == FOLLOWERS || _pageType == FOLLOWING) {
        cellUser = [self.users objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        text = cellUser.userDescription.text;
        if (text == nil) {
            return 70;
        }
    } else {
        cellPost = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        text = cellPost.text;
    }

    CGSize boundingSize = CGSizeMake(245, CGFLOAT_MAX);
    CGSize requiredSize = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"TisaMobiPro" size:15]
                               constrainedToSize:boundingSize
                                   lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    CGFloat textHeight = requiredSize.height;
    CGFloat cellHeight = textHeight + 40;
    if ([cellPost.text isEqualToString:self.post.text]) {
        cellHeight += 44;
        if (cellHeight < 114) {
            cellHeight = 114;
        }
    } else {
        if (cellHeight < 70) {
            cellHeight = 70;
        }
    }

    if (cellPost.repostedBy != nil && cellPost.youReposted.boolValue == NO && _pageType != CONVERSATION) {
        cellHeight += 27;
    }

    return cellHeight;

}
```

If I remove most of the code and only have, e.g. `return 100` the tableView's scrolling performance is much improved. Can you spot or give suggestions on something in my implantation that could cause this performance issue?

Comment: Blind guess: `[text sizeWithFont:...]` has to do a lot of computations. But I'm not even remotely confident. Use a profiler.

Comment: Can you determine the heights of the strings up front and cache them? This method is run repeatedly (as you can see) so if the size doesn't change (or changes infrequently) then it's very wasteful.

Comment: @H2CO3, Yes, when I "disabled" hide system libraries it seems like size with font is the main problem here. Wain, will try do do that. Unless you know a simpler more effective method instead of sizeWith font. Didn't have this issue with iOS6, only now with iOS7.

Comment: Is that a custom font you are using? How about you create it once in ViewDidLoad, store it in a module variable and just use that?

Comment: Good idea. Not sure how much performance improvement that would be. Calculating the height of the text seems to be the major issue. Also noticed that `sizeWithFont` is deprecated. I'm now using `text boundingRectWithSize`instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heights are calculated before the `– tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`  is called and for all the number of cells. 
If you are deploying on iOS7 you can use the `- tableView:estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:`, using that method you can defer this calculation while scrolling the tableview. That means that the method `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` is called basically when a cell is displayed. The estimation could be a fixed number close to the average of your TVC or based on some math faster than the one that you implemented.
Thanks to the estimation the TV can set its content size an scroll bar height and doesn't need to calculate each height for 100 of rows in one shot. The payback could be a lag during scrolling because the TV is calculating the actual row height.

Answer (score 1):

If you are targeting iOS7 you can use the `NSTableView` property: `estimatedRowHeight`.

From the Apple docs:

> Providing a nonnegative estimate of the height of rows can improve the
>   performance of loading the table view. If the table contains variable
>   height rows, it might be expensive to calculate all their heights when
>   the table loads. Using estimation allows you to defer some of the cost
>   of geometry calculation from load time to scrolling time.

Also:

> **Every time a
>   table view is displayed, it calls tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:**
>   on the delegate for **each of its rows**

If you have to use `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` cache the heights as @Waine suggests.